# Save category URl with / symbol

Tags: url-rewrite, category-tree

I'm trying to save category url as `sarees/applique-work` as url path but it's being saved as `sarees-applique-work` . How I can save `/` in the URL ?

Comment: I reckon creating a "sarees" parent category with a "applique-work" child category is not an option? This would result in the URL that you specified for the child category.

Comment: it's there. Though I've to remove the main category(sarees) from url if you're in a sub-category and I'm re-writing URL.php model to achieve it. ` /*if (null === $parentPath) {
            $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        }
        elseif ($parentPath == '/') {*/
            $parentPath = '';
       // } . `Now If I'm visiting sarees->craft->applique-work, it shoyld show url like sarees/applique-work due to which I'm tring to save sarees/applique-work as a url for applique-work category.